# Italian term for returning to the original tempo, but with more energy (or slightly faster)?

Tags: terminology, tempo

Following a 'rall. poco a poco' in the previous phrase, ending in a fermata pause, I wish to indicate that the new phrase is slightly faster than 'a tempo'. I had initially thought 'a tempo con moto' would be appropriate, however I haven't seen a marking like this in music so I am unsure. Would 'a tempo con moto' make sense and convey what I want?

Answer (score 8):

I think this makes little sense. "A tempo" specifically means to *return* to a previous tempo, so there's no point in qualifying it to mean "*not* the previous tempo".

You're better off using absolute rather than relative indications, such as *Allegro* ... *rallentando* ... *piu allegro*.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd understand what you meant, but it's a little weird. "Con moto" is typically attached to a tempo marking like "Allegro". I think that "A tempo, piu mosso" would work.

Alternatively, there's no reason you have to stick to the Italian markings nowadays. You can simply write "faster than before" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

'A tempo but slightly faster'.  Or' if you're obsessed about doing it in Italian, 'a tempo ma più mosso'.

No need for 'poco a poco' after 'rall'.   'Rall.' means 'gradually getting slower'.   If you're using notation software and care about playback, be sure to extend the dotted line.   Likewise, don't expect Sibelius etc. to recognise 'a tempo ma più mosso'.  Turn off playback for the text object and add a hidden mm mark.

Answer (score 0):

a tempo, or tempo primo if during the composition tempo changes few times. Tempo primo is tempo from the beginning. A tempo is earlier tempo before last change.

Comment: Hi @user17493, and welcome to Music.SE! There's a reason why I don't think this answers the question. Your suggestion to use "a tempo" won't work because GoatsWearHats indicates that the new tempo should be slightly faster than the previous tempo. There doesn't seem to be an indication that the original tempo is at the slightly faster pace that the next section (following the fermata) needs. Could you edit your answer to include a discussion of GoatsWearHats's suggestion to use "a tempo con moto"? If this doesn't do the trick, then is there something else that could be used?

Answer (score 0):

A tempo ma con fuoco?

That would be something like "old speed but with vigor".  In general, "ma" is good for finetuning a specification, like in "Largo ma non troppo" (slow but not too much so).